# Camel ProducerTemplate send to a JMS message property

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

In my camel project, i need to send some message to a **gateway** (which will receive it as a **JMS** message).

For gateway, besides the message text, there will be some other string properties using `jmsMessage.getStringProperty("xxx");`

In my camel project, my code is something like below:

```
@Produce(uri = "xxx")
private ProducerTemplate template;

@Override
public void sendToQueue(String textMessage, Map<String, String> properties) {
    template.sendBody(textMessage);
}
```

I know if I just send a string text message I will invoke the sendBody method which receive one argument. I just wondering how should I sent the properties using camel and on the other side they can receive the properties as **JMS** TextMessage string properties.

Also what's the meaning for camel headers, it's also a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
template.sendBodyAndHeaders(textMessage, properties);
```

As JMS properties is mapped to Camel Message headers. And hence why you can use the `sendBodyAndHeaders` method to include the JMS properties.

Comment: Also, on the other side if i want to get the jms property from consumed. I just use exchange.getIn().getHeader("xxx")? Thanks